# Determine complexity class or big-o

Tags: java, big-o

What is the big O for the following problem?

```
public static void mystery(int[] list)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < list.length/2; i++)
   {
      int j = list.length-1-i;
      int temp = list[i];
      list[i] = list[j];
      list[j] = temp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's O(n), since it loops the array only once.